# Accessing passed data through ajax call in my python script

Tags: python, ajax, django

I've been breaking my head since morning over this, but can't get it work. Basically, what I want to do is that upon clicking 'Send' in an html page, the account number (it's value in a textfield) should be sent to my python script. Now, how can I access the passed account number in my python script. I'm using django.

This is the ajax call from the html page:

```
$('#b2').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url : "../../cgi-bin/testjson.py",
        type : "post",
        datatype : "json",
        data : {
            ac_number : $("#account_number").val()
        },
        success : function(response) {
            var handle = document.getElementById("displaytext");
            handle.innerHTML += '<p> Button clicked</p>';
            handle.innerHTML += '<p> Value received is: </p>' + response.data[0];
        }
    });    
});
```

Comment: Is the click function executed? What prints `console.log($("#account_number").val());`? Is django called? What happens when you manually call django (with something like ff poster)?

Comment: Yes, the function is executed. I'm even getting response from my python script. The only problem is how to refer to the passed ac_number in my python script. My python script looks like this: #!/usr/local/bin/python

import json
import sys

sys.stdout.write("Content-Type: application/json")
sys.stdout.write("\n")
sys.stdout.write("\n")




mylist = []
mylist.append('c')
mylist.append('d')
mylist.append("e")
    

    
    
jsonobj = { 'data': mylist }
sys.stdout.write(json.dumps(jsonobj))

Comment: Is it not easier to create a real django endpoint here instead of this cgi stuff?

Comment: Like RickyA, I can't understand why you have a separate CGI script rather than processing the POST in a Django view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your python file:

```
import sys
import cgi


sys.stdout.write("Content-Type: application/json")
sys.stdout.write("\n") 
sys.stdout.write("\n")

form = cgi.FieldStorage() 

sys.stdout.write(json.dumps({ 'data': form.getvalue('ac_number')}))
```

Answer (score 0):

In django so you can access `request.POST`:

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^testjson', 'testjson.views.testjson'),
)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponse

def testjson(request):
    ret = "not a post"
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ret = str(request.POST)
    return HttpResponse(ret)
```